# Javascript: (Math.floor(Math.random() * songs) + 1)+'.mp3'

Tags: javascript

I currently have this js code:

```
audio.src = path + 'assets/music/'+(Math.floor(Math.random() * songs) +      1)+'.mp3'
```

And on my website, I have folder assets/music/1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3, so it
picks a random song and it plays the song. (Math.random)

I prefer not to use math.random because sometimes it plays the same track twice and it's annoying.

So any solutions?

Website: http://selen.xyz
The javascript code: http://selen.xyz/animate.js

Comment: Randomise the list of songs up front to create a randomised playlist where each song only appears once.

Comment: The process of generating a "randomized playlist" is often called "shuffling". You make an array containing all the song numbers in order, then you shuffle it.

Comment: Look up Fisher-Yates shuffle

Comment: See [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/1529630)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.slice()` to create a copy of array containing path to file, create empty array `songs`, call `.splice()` with `Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length)` to retrieve random item from `copy` , remove selected item from `copy` , when `songs` `.length` is `arr` original array `.length` , `songs` should be filled with pseudo-randomly selected items , set audio element to use items within `songs` array as `src`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  copy = arr.slice(0),
  songs = [];
while (songs.length < arr.length) {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
  songs[songs.length] = "assets/music/" + copy[n] + ".mp3";
  copy.splice(n, 1)
}
document.writeln(songs.join("<br>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the last played song ID in localstorage (undefined in the first instance)
2. Generate a random song id (which does not match the stored value)
3. Store the new song ID in localstorage

.

```
var songs = 10,
    last_song_id = localStorage.getItem('last_song_id'),
    song_id;

do {
    song_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs) + 1;
} while(last_song_id === song_id);

localStorage.setItem('last_song_id', song_id);

audio.src = path + 'assets/music/' + song_id;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.
Although I do not understand what code I should implement now.

Comment: Step 2 is basically what the OP was asking how to do.